# Build Wheel Error when i installing JupyterLab

Tags: python, jupyter-lab, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

After downloading VS2017 build tools And Python 3.9, i try to install JupyterLab :

Configuration

- Operating System: Windows 10 Pro 64-bit (10.0, Build 19041) (19041.vb_release.191206-1406)
- Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5300U CPU @ 2.30GHz (4 CPUs), ~2.3GHz
- Memory: 16384MB RAM
- Python version : 3.9.0
- IDLE : Vs2017 Professional 15.9.28 (include Build tools)

```
pip install jupyterlab
```

and i get this :

```
Collecting jupyterlab
  Using cached jupyterlab-2.2.9-py3-none-any.whl (7.9 MB)
Collecting jinja2>=2.10
  Using cached Jinja2-2.11.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (125 kB)
Collecting tornado!=6.0.0,!=6.0.1,!=6.0.2
  Using cached tornado-6.0.4.tar.gz (496 kB)
Collecting jupyterlab-server<2.0,>=1.1.5
  Using cached jupyterlab_server-1.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (29 kB)
Collecting notebook>=4.3.1
  Using cached notebook-6.1.4-py3-none-any.whl (9.5 MB)
Collecting MarkupSafe>=0.23
  Using cached MarkupSafe-1.1.1.tar.gz (19 kB)
Collecting requests
  Using cached requests-2.24.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
Collecting jsonschema>=3.0.1
  Using cached jsonschema-3.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (56 kB)
Collecting json5
  Using cached json5-0.9.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)
Collecting ipykernel
  Using cached ipykernel-5.3.4-py3-none-any.whl (120 kB)
Collecting terminado>=0.8.3
  Using cached terminado-0.9.1-py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
Collecting jupyter-client>=5.3.4
  Using cached jupyter_client-6.1.7-py3-none-any.whl (108 kB)
Collecting argon2-cffi
  Using cached argon2-cffi-20.1.0.tar.gz (1.8 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Collecting prometheus-client
  Using cached prometheus_client-0.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (53 kB)
Collecting pyzmq>=17
  Using cached pyzmq-19.0.2-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (695 kB)
Collecting nbconvert
  Using cached nbconvert-6.0.7-py3-none-any.whl (552 kB)
Collecting ipython-genutils
  Using cached ipython_genutils-0.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
Collecting traitlets>=4.2.1
  Using cached traitlets-5.0.5-py3-none-any.whl (100 kB)
Collecting jupyter-core>=4.6.1
  Using cached jupyter_core-4.6.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (83 kB)
Collecting Send2Trash
  Using cached Send2Trash-1.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
Collecting nbformat
  Using cached nbformat-5.0.8-py3-none-any.whl (172 kB)
Collecting chardet<4,>=3.0.2
  Using cached chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17
  Using cached certifi-2020.6.20-py2.py3-none-any.whl (156 kB)
Collecting idna<3,>=2.5
  Using cached idna-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
Collecting urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1
  Using cached urllib3-1.25.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl (127 kB)
Collecting six>=1.11.0
  Using cached six-1.15.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting attrs>=17.4.0
  Using cached attrs-20.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (48 kB)
Collecting pyrsistent>=0.14.0
  Using cached pyrsistent-0.17.3.tar.gz (106 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\yasse\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from jsonschema>=3.0.1->jupyterlab-server<2.0,>=1.1.5->jupyterlab) (50.3.2)
Collecting ipython>=5.0.0
  Using cached ipython-7.18.1-py3-none-any.whl (786 kB)
Collecting pywinpty>=0.5; os_name == "nt"
  Using cached pywinpty-0.5.7.tar.gz (49 kB)
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.1
  Using cached python_dateutil-2.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (227 kB)
Collecting cffi>=1.0.0
  Using cached cffi-1.14.3-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (179 kB)
Collecting mistune<2,>=0.8.1
  Using cached mistune-0.8.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Collecting testpath
  Using cached testpath-0.4.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (163 kB)
Collecting defusedxml
  Using cached defusedxml-0.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
Collecting nbclient<0.6.0,>=0.5.0
  Using cached nbclient-0.5.1-py3-none-any.whl (65 kB)
Collecting jupyterlab-pygments
  Using cached jupyterlab_pygments-0.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.6 kB)
Collecting bleach
  Using cached bleach-3.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (145 kB)
Collecting pandocfilters>=1.4.1
  Using cached pandocfilters-1.4.3.tar.gz (16 kB)
Collecting entrypoints>=0.2.2
  Using cached entrypoints-0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting pygments>=2.4.1
  Using cached Pygments-2.7.2-py3-none-any.whl (948 kB)
Collecting pywin32>=1.0; sys_platform == "win32"
  Using cached pywin32-228-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (9.1 MB)
Collecting colorama; sys_platform == "win32"
  Using cached colorama-0.4.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Collecting decorator
  Using cached decorator-4.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.2 kB)
Collecting pickleshare
  Using cached pickleshare-0.7.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.9 kB)
Collecting prompt-toolkit!=3.0.0,!=3.0.1,<3.1.0,>=2.0.0
  Using cached prompt_toolkit-3.0.8-py3-none-any.whl (355 kB)
Collecting backcall
  Using cached backcall-0.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting jedi>=0.10
  Using cached jedi-0.17.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.4 MB)
Collecting pycparser
  Using cached pycparser-2.20-py2.py3-none-any.whl (112 kB)
Collecting nest-asyncio
  Using cached nest_asyncio-1.4.2-py3-none-any.whl (5.3 kB)
Collecting async-generator
  Using cached async_generator-1.10-py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Collecting webencodings
  Using cached webencodings-0.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting packaging
  Using cached packaging-20.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (37 kB)
Collecting wcwidth
  Using cached wcwidth-0.2.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (30 kB)
Collecting parso<0.8.0,>=0.7.0
  Using cached parso-0.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (109 kB)
Collecting pyparsing>=2.0.2
  Using cached pyparsing-2.4.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (67 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for tornado, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for MarkupSafe, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for pyrsistent, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for pywinpty, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for pandocfilters, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Building wheels for collected packages: argon2-cffi
  Building wheel for argon2-cffi (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\yasse\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\yasse\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\yasse\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpal71y1ke'
       cwd: C:\Users\yasse\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-bubdgxpe\argon2-cffi
  Complete output (17 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\argon2
  copying src\argon2\exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\argon2
  copying src\argon2\low_level.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\argon2
  copying src\argon2\_ffi_build.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\argon2
  copying src\argon2\_legacy.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\argon2
  copying src\argon2\_password_hasher.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\argon2
  copying src\argon2\_utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\argon2
  copying src\argon2\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\argon2
  copying src\argon2\__main__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\argon2
  running build_clib
  building 'argon2' library
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for argon2-cffi
Failed to build argon2-cffi
ERROR: Could not build wheels for argon2-cffi which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

After checking some forum i found that Errors is from The Build tools but I install it And i don't know why its not working !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried installing the `wheel` module ?

```
pip3 install wheel
```

Comment: But i fixed by re-install all of this new python3.9 and also new VS with all build wheel and tools